# How to refresh the detail when the selected master item changes?

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

I have a master detail form with 2 grids: customers = master, orders = detail. How can I refresh the detail when I select a new customer from the master grid? Here is my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        AutoLotEntities context = new AutoLotEntities();
        BindingSource customerBindingSource;
        BindingSource orderBindingSource;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            customerBindingSource = new BindingSource();
            orderBindingSource = new BindingSource();

            customerBindingSource.DataSource = context.Customers;
            orderBindingSource.DataMember = "Orders";
            orderBindingSource.DataSource = customerBindingSource.DataSource;

            grdCustomers.DataSource = customerBindingSource;
            grdOrders.DataSource = orderBindingSource;
        }
    }
```

I managed to do it with the help of IDE generated code in the Form1.Desginer.cs but I want to do it by hand with non-generated code to see how this thing works.

Answer (score 0):

Create a method which generates your grid for orders using the Customers as its context. Then create an overridden method which accepts another parameter (for example customer id) then reload your data grid with it.